# Does Azure Search result guarantee order for * query?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'd like to manage AzSearch documents (indexed items) by AzSearch C# SDK.

What I try to do is to list up documents by query result (mostly `*` result) continuously and edit values of them.

To list up query result is as below;

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyIndexModel>> GetListAsync(string query, bool isNext = false)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query)) query = "*";
    DocumentSearchResult list;
    if (!isNext)
    {
        list = await _indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync(query);
    }
    else
    {
        list = await _indexClient.Documents.ContinueSearchAsync(ContinuationToken);
    }
    ContinuationToken = list.ContinuationToken;
    return list.Results.Select(o => o.Document.ToIndexModel());
}
```

One requirement is to *jump* to the n-th list of items. Since AzSearch does not provide *paging*, I'd like to know whether it gives ordered list or not.

If we do *not* update document count (not index further), does AzSearch give unchanged/ordered list so I can get the same document for `jump to 80th list` by running `ContinueSearchAsync()` method 80 times?

Do I have to maintain another lookup table for my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

* is a wildcard query. Documents matching a wildcard query are given the same constant score in ranking because there's no way to measure how close a document is to *. Further, order between the same score document is not guaranteed. A document matching '*' can be ranked 1st in one response and 7th position in another even when the same query were issued.

In order to get consistent ordering for wildcard queries, I suggest passing in an $orderBy clause, search=*&$orderBy=id asc for example. Azure Search does support paging via $skip and $top. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-pagination-page-layout) provides the guidance.